# Different form of equation of a straight line

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations, angle

I have been told that any straight line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be represented by two parameters $(p,\theta)$ and the equation:

$$x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta)-p=0$$

But am struggling to see intuitively why this equation gives a straight line. Can anyone explain to me in terms of geometry what the parameters $p$ and $\theta$ represent in terms of the line (i.e. like when we represent a line as $y=mx+c$, $m$ is the gradient and $c$ is the intercept, what is $\theta$ and $p$ in this setting?)?

Comment: Hint: rewrite as $\bigg\langle \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix} \bigg\rangle = p$.

Comment: You could also write the equation as
$$
\bigg\langle \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} - \pmatrix{x_0\\y_0}, \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix} \bigg\rangle = 0
$$
where $(x_0,y_0)$ are the coordinates of any point on the line.

Answer (score 1):

You may rewrite the equation in the familiar form $y=mx+c$,

$$y=-\cot\theta\> x+p\csc\theta$$

to identify

$$m = -\cot\theta,\>\>\>\>\>p= c\sin\theta$$

Knowing that $m$ is the gradient, measured by $m=\tan\alpha$, with $\alpha$ being the angle between the line and the $x$-axis, you can rewrite $m=\tan(\frac\pi2 + \theta)$ and deduce that $\theta$ is the angle between the given line and the $y$-axis. (See the graph below.)

Similarly, knowing that $c$ is the $y$-intercept, then $p=c\cos\theta$ represents the distance of the line from the origin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes called a "normal" equation. Here, $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is a normal vector to the line, and therefore $\theta$ is the angle between the normal and the $OX$-axis. $p$ is the distance from the line to the origin.